# Is it possible to filter data from sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to do an app for a bank that shows credits/debits of it , but when i filter it in the textbox, data is not found !
Hope you can help me !

```
        string filter = "";
        string command = "SELECT * FROM Movimentos WHERE [Tipo de Movimento] IN('Crédito')";

        if (textTipodeMovimento.Text != "")
        {
            filter = filter + "[Tipo de Movimento] LIKE  '%" + textTipodeMovimento.Text + "%'AND";
        }

        if (filter.Length > 0)
        {
            Sqldata.DataSource = SqlDataSource1;
            string FinalFilter = filter.Remove(filter.Length - 3);
            SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = command + FinalFilter;
            Sqldata.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Sqldata.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to do an app for a bank"* And yet you're making an app that is **wide open** to injection? Before anything you need to fix that. Before you start making applications, especially for something like this, you **need** to understand things like Security; it is paramount in every application and people are going  to be very upset if as a result of an application *you* made their money is stolen or their personal details are compromised.

Comment: @Larnu Is just a test , nothing definitive ! I just can't figure it out because i'm trying to filter some data and when i filter Credit/Debit it appears but when i filter the value of anything it doesnt appear , my objective is a user only can see credits and not debits

Comment: Then parametrise your query; otherwise the User could see what ever they want right now. A "test" does not mean you can use bad coding practices or create huge security holes.

Comment: @Larnu I've been working in C# for like 1 week , i don't know everything about this language , i finding some help here ... How can i do that tho ?

Comment: What you're after is [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8). Parametrisation of SQL commands is incredibly important. If you're not familiar with it, I suggest have a read up on [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Larnu It works but not the way i want , imagine that you have a table and you want to filter any type of data , I want to appear the entire line relates to this value, for example, date, Name, Description, Value by only filter 1 table field

Comment: I think you need to explain your goals better here. What you say in the above comment, and what you ask don't tally.

Comment: @Larnu my goal is what i said in last comment .

Comment: But what you're asking should be in your question, not the comments. If you're question is not reflective of your requirements then it's not clear what you're asking. Make your question representative of your needs. Include sample data and expected results, etc.

Answer (score -1):

If to only correct your code, it'll be like:

```
    string command = "SELECT * FROM Movimentos WHERE [Tipo de Movimento]  = 'Crédito'"; // no need to use IN statement if there is only a check for 1 value

    if (textTipodeMovimento.Text != "")
    {
        command += String.Format(" AND lower([Tipo de Movimento]) LIKE  '%{0}%'", textTipodeMovimento.Text.ToLower());
    }

    Sqldata.DataBind();
```

Comment: This doesn't address the injection issue at all. Also, why are you applying `LOWER` to the column `[Tipo de Movimento]`? That could have significant performance implications.

Comment: I wasn't the person that answered here @DiogoPeixoto :)

Comment: @Larnu, I used ToLower() method to ignore case while searching for data. So it will display all rows containing 'Test' and 'test' and 'TEST', for example

Comment: How do you know the OP is using a Case Sensitive Collation? They don't mention they are; and `LOWER` will be a performance hit either way.

Comment: @Larnu, I don't know that. Though LOWER will be a performance hit, what will you do if you need records containing 'test', 'Test' and 'TEST', when you don't know how is it stored in DB and how the user will type the keyword?

Comment: use a case insensitive collation, or a persisted column with the value already in lowercase.

Comment: @Larnu, Dunno what kind of tasks you did resolve, but look: I have a column named Message in my table. I want to make a search for all messages containing value 'France'. So it have to show me all messages even if they contain ether 'france' or 'France' or 'FRANCE' or whatever like that. And it have to show the message as it is, without lowercasing or whatever. I used LOWER() due to this reason

Comment: Which brings me back to my question, @Kharatbek: *"How do you know the OP is using a Case Sensitive Collation?"*. They don't mention they are, so where have you got this extra insight from?

Comment: @Larnu, What do you want from me??? I just suggested him one solution, and've added Lower() if he will need that. He easily can remove that. It is not a problem